# Run Msbuild task only on projects that have some property

Tags: xml, msbuild, csproj, msbuild-task

I want to run some MSbuild task, let's say build, on multiple .csproj projects, but only on those that contain a certain property.

Assume I have two projects, A.csproj, B.csproj and B.csproj has `<ShouldBuild>true</ShouldBuild>` property.

Then running this command:

```
<MSBuild Projects="**\*.csproj" Targets="Build" />
```

Will cause only B.csproj to build, while ignoring A.csproj, because it doesn't have the required property.

Is this possible? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

### Solution Filter

Are the projects in a solution (.sln)? You can create a Solution filter file (.slnf) that contains project B and then build using the .slnf file. The project files and the solution files would be unchanged. See "[Filtered solutions in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions?view=vs-2022)".

But a solution filter is a completely different approach from what was asked.

### Batching

Coming back to the approach raised in the question, I would not put the `ShouldBuild` property into each project. MSBuild doesn't support querying another project for its defined properties and you need to know the value of `ShouldBuild` at the point of the `MSBuild` task.

The following MSBuild code:

1. Uses an `ItemDefinitionGroup` to define a metadata item of `ShouldBuild` for an `ItemGroup` named `Project`. Every member item of `Project` will have the `ShouldBuild` metadata. `ShouldBuild`'s default value is `true`.
2. Explicitly adds project A to the `Project` with `ShouldBuild` set to false, overriding the default value.
3. Add other projects while excluding projects already in the ItemGroup, i.e. project A is not added again.

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <Project>
      <ShouldBuild>true</ShouldBuild>
    </Project>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Project Include="A\A.csproj">
      <ShouldBuild>false</ShouldBuild>
    </Project>
    <Project Include="**\*.csproj" Exclude="@(Project)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now with the `Project` ItemGroup, you can use tsk batching within a target.

```
  <Target ... >
    <MSBuild Projects="@(Project)" Targets="Build" Condition="'%(Project.ShouldBuild)' = 'true'" />
  </Target>
```